# Recyclerview start from Bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am loading Pictures and Strings into a Recyclerview. I once had it that the setStackfrombottom was working. But now it is not. I dont know why. This is my Code :

```
MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(chatsList, Chat_Room.this);
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
```

The ChatsList is a List, which contains a constructor of Strings.
What else can I try?

**EDIT**

It was not working because I used Picasso. After I changed it to Glide it was working better and more smooth. And after I set the Adapter I did this:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

To scroll to the last position.
And now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recieving the Data from Firebase. So it was already in the right order.
After I set the Adapter, I scrolled to the last postition:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

So it scrolls now to the last position. (The -1 because the Adapter starts counting at 0 )

Answer (score 2):

```
manager.setReverseLayout=true
```

You can use above property.

Comment: although this is not what I need. With reverseLayout it is not at the Bottom/Top

Comment: I put pictures in the Question

Comment: With set reverseLayout the Messages are not in the Right order.

Comment: The problem is that I am loading Images with Picasso. And I think that this changes the height of the Recyclerview after I stack it to the end. How can I change this

Comment: If you are using a picasso. For that please use Glide lib.

Comment: Does Glide has a Placeholder class? How can I set the Image. I cant find it

Comment: when I try that it says: Cannot resolve method 'placeholder(int)'

Comment: Please refer this link    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076654/android-glide-placeholder-size

Comment: I did the same thing. But placeholder still is red underlined

Comment: You should declare inform :      .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);

Comment: When I do it like you said: `Glide.with(context)
                                .load("http://lorempixel.com/150/150")
                                .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image_placeholder))
                                .override(100, 100)
                                .dontAnimate()
                                .into(pictureHolder.myImage);` It is still not working

Comment: .placeholder(...) is still red.

Comment: Placeholder is says, If your Image is not loaded any reason than placeholder is load instead of. So. once u should try first use color instead of drawable.            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.placeholder_gray)))

Comment: I tried another version of Glide, and now it is working fine. But it still dont starts from the bottom