# fixed placeholder in the center of image view

Tags: android, imageview, resize, placeholder

By using **Glide** I set **placeholder** on image view but the problem is, it is shown on whole image view, I want my placeholder size to be 50dp/50dp but image should be `setScale(fitXY)`.

I solved the problem in `glide listener`, I am resizing image view on runtime, if it get image from server then imageview **width,height(x,y)** if not then **(x,y)**.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(news.getUrlToImage())
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(131, 131);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    holder.NewsImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(495, 360);
                    holder.NewsImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    holder.NewsImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    return false;
                }
            }).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder).dontAnimate())
            .into(holder.NewsImage);
```

But the problem is, if there is no image from server it show placeholder of **size(50,50)** fine and when it has image and glide take some mili seconds to upload image, in that time it shows placeholder on whole image view.

**HELP ME**

[image: I want this]

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076654/android-glide-placeholder-size

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes, this is pixels value, it has nothing to do with size of placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:scaleType="center"` in xml.

Then, Glide makes your real image fitted center and placeholder is located in center by xml.
You can check the details in [Glide: load drawable but don't scale placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235413/glide-load-drawable-but-dont-scale-placeholder)

If you want that scaleType to "fitXY"
Try below.

```
holder.NewsImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
Glide.with(context)
        .load(news.getUrlToImage())
        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(131, 131);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                holder.NewsImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(495, 360);
                holder.NewsImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                holder.NewsImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                return false;
            }
        }).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder).dontAnimate())
        .into(holder.NewsImage);
```

Comment: I want my image to `fitXY` and placeholder in the **center** but of smaller size, as you can see in above image

Comment: Then, first setScaleType="center" then, change scaleType to "fitXY" when resource is ready.

Comment: I am having problem on `onResourceReady`. when resource is ready it shows full size placeholder for few mili seconds.

Comment: It is working fine on`onLoadFaild` because I am resizing **imageview** in it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .priority(Priority.NORMAL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderImageName)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .fitCenter()
            .error(R.drawable.errorImageName);
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load("ImagePath")
            .apply(options)
            .into(Img_imageView);
```